# nls fit works but fails inside geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I want to use ggplot to fit an nls function to some data. The nls function is working well when used outside of geom_smooth() but inside it fails.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 4, 12, 35, 100), 
                     response = c(0.015, 0.03673, 0.07212, 0.1027, 0.1286, 0.1858, 0.1812)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df.fit <- nls(response ~ k0 + (ki*concentration/(KI + concentration)), df, start = list(k0 = 0.001, ki = 0.18, KI = 1))
coef(df.fit)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(concentration, response))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = F, method.args = list(formula = response ~ k0 + (ki*concentration/(KI + concentration)), 
                                                         start = list(k0 = 0.001, ki = 0.18, KI = 1)))
plot
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify `nls` fits in `geom_smooth` using a character vector. From the help file:

```
  method: Smoothing method (function) to use, accepts either a
          character vector, e.g. ‘"auto"’, ‘"lm"’, ‘"glm"’, ‘"gam"’,
          ‘"loess"’ or a function, e.g. ‘MASS::rlm’ or ‘mgcv::gam’,
          ‘stats::lm’, or ‘stats::loess’.
```

You can specify a new vector of predictions and plot them using `geom_line`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 4, 12, 35, 100),
                     response = c(0.015, 0.03673, 0.07212, 0.1027, 0.1286, 0.1858, 0.1812)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df.fit <- nls(response ~ k0 + (ki*concentration/(KI + concentration)), df, start = list(k0 = 0.001, ki = 0.18, KI = 1))
coef(df.fit)
df$pred <- predict(df.fit)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(concentration, response))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(x = concentration, y = pred))
plot
```

Comment: Is this a recent change? I've done it before and the code in that old script still runs fine. I have also seen a comment from Hadley Wickham on someone's post who used an nls fit inside of geom_smooth and he didn't call that out as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm embarrassed for having asked the question now. I just needed to change the variables "response" and "concentration" inside the geom_smooth formula to "y" and "x" as follows.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(concentration = c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 4, 12, 35, 100), 
                     response = c(0.015, 0.03673, 0.07212, 0.1027, 0.1286, 0.1858, 0.1812)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df.fit <- nls(response ~ k0 + (ki*concentration/(KI + concentration)), df, start = list(k0 = 0.001, ki = 0.18, KI = 1))
coef(df.fit)

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(concentration, response))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = F, method.args = list(formula = y ~ k0 + (ki*x/(KI + x)), 
                                                         start = list(k0 = 0.001, ki = 0.18, KI = 1)))
plot
```